# ¿Cual es la forma correcta de escribir un path a un archivo?

Tags: javascript, rutas, filesystem

Estaba montando un servidor local bastante basico que lee un array guardado en un .json y en mi pc funciona correctamente utilizando la ruta "./archivosMemoria/products.json" Pero a la hora de conectar el servidor desde otra pc no localiza el archivo y la ruta debe ser "../archivosMemoria/products.json" La unica diferencia que encuentro es que yo uso Linux y la otra pc usa Windows pero no se si eso influya o por que sea. adjunto imagen de las carpetas. Yo quiero acceder desde "productManager.js" a "products.json"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Utilizo un constructor en una clase para poder asignarle la ruta a una variable en el archivo productManager.js asi:

```
this.path = "./archivosMemoria/products.json";
```

Y en ambas pc los archivos estan en la misma carpeta y se abren igual pero tiene eso que se debe modificar el path para que lo lea bien en la otra pc

Comment: ¿Cómo estás corriendolo? Puedes pasar capturas de las 2 terminales. Es posible que estés iniciando el programa en diferentes carpetas y como son rutas relativas no funciona.

Comment: agrega el código desde donde estás leyendo ese archivo? danos un contexto para poder ayudarte

Comment: Ahi añadi el codigo de como asigno el path y cambie la foto de los archivos para que vean que esta todo dentro de una carpeta que es igual en ambas pc, literalmente es la misma carpeta copiada y pegada en la otra pc

Comment: Se abren igual. Bueno, ¿y cómo es que los estás abriendo? Si lo estás haciendo por consola, ¿puedes cargar capturas de ambas consolas?

Answer (score 0):

**Te dejo varias formas de acceder a los archivos.**

> C:\Documents\Newsletters\Summer2018.pdf

Ruta de acceso de archivo absoluta desde la raíz de la unidad C:.

> \Program Files\Custom Utilities\StringFinder.exe

Ruta de acceso absoluta desde la raíz de la unidad actual.

> 2018\January.xlsx

Ruta de acceso relativa a un archivo en un subdirectorio del directorio actual.

> ..\Publications\TravelBrochure.pdf

Ruta de acceso relativa a un archivo en un directorio a partir del directorio actual.

> C:\Projects\apilibrary\apilibrary.sln

Ruta de acceso absoluta a un archivo desde la raíz de la unidad C:.

> C:Projects\apilibrary\apilibrary.sln

Ruta de acceso relativa desde el directorio actual de la unidad C:.

También puedes verificar la información o cualquier otra duda en este [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats)